# FROM keyword not found where expected while filtering data

Tags: oracle, plsql

I got one error

```
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoices) AS numberOfRows 
    FROM invoices ORDER BY Id DESC) WHERE rownum <= 1
```

I am begginer in Oracle SQL, but as I see here I have FROM keyword and it looks everythink OK.
I try to modify this query something like but still get another error

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

SELECT * FROM
      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoices) AS numberOfRows 
    FROM invoices ORDER BY Id DESC) WHERE rownum <= 1
```

What is wrong in first `select query ?` What is missing ? Since I check everything, start from special character `(`  `.` `,` `)`

Also I try this kind of solution and get error

```
ORA-00936: missing expression

SELECT * FROM (SELECT , (SELECT COUNT() FROM invoices) AS numberOfRows FROM invoices ORDER BY Id DESC) WHERE rownum <= 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The railroad diagram in the documentation:

[image: select-list]

... shows that you can either use `*` on its own, or `<something>.*` along with other columns or expressions. So you need to precede your `*` with the table name or an alias:

```
SELECT * FROM 
      (SELECT i.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoices) AS numberOfRows 
    FROM invoices i ORDER BY Id DESC) WHERE rownum <= 1
```

If you're on a recent version of Oracle you can do this much more simply with:

```
select i.*, count(*) over () as numberOfRows
from invoices i
order by id desc
fetch first row only
```

On older version you still need a subquery, but only one level:

```
select *
from (
  select i.*, count(*) over () as numberOfRows
  from invoices i
  order by id desc
)
where rownum = 1
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b3468e040c72dfc3631d659ad9fa8a51)

Comment: WooW. Thank you for explanation. It works perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

looks like the FROM is missing from this select "SELECT *,"

SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM invoices) AS numberOfRows
FROM invoices ORDER BY Id DESC) WHERE rownum <= 1

Comment: No, it is not. I try this solution